# Check and calulate time period between datetime in sql 2005

Tags: sql, datetime, between

I need to check if any work time period is between datetime and calculate hours between for work hours sum grater than 8 hours.

Sample data:

```
1. Work time: 07:00 - 17:00 and datetime for checking 06:00-22:00
Answer: 2 hour 
2. Work time: 13:00 - 23:00 and datetime for checking 06:00-22:00
Answer: 1 hour (only 1 hour is grater 8 hours and between 06:00-22:00 )
3. Work time: 19:00 - 05:00 and datetime for checking 22:00-06:00
Answer: 2 hour (only 2 hour is grater 8 hours and between 22:00-06:00 )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [T-SQL DateDiff - partition by "full hours ago", rather than "times minutes turned 00 since"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289547/t-sql-datediff-partition-by-full-hours-ago-rather-than-times-minutes-turne)

Basically, DATEDIFF(HOUR, endTime, startTime).  Then, subtract your result from 8 to get the difference (if they were "under" time, the difference will be negative).